# GitHub Pages repo is not loading work, what did I mess up?

Tags: github-pages

I created a todo app and had it using GitHub Pages. It does not pull anything other than the readme.md when clicking the live link. I do not understand what I messed up here. I have a different repo using same style of programming that is working fine.

Issue repo: https://github.com/jsfilas/todo-app

Similar working repo: https://github.com/jsfilas/Restaurant-Page

Comment: Hey @jsfilas, could you please share with us the command lines you tried before you tried to pull the repo?, in this way we can reproduce the example...

Answer (score 0):

Restaurant-Page is deployed to a gh-pages *branch*. There does not appear to be a gh-pages branch for todo-app. You have to put your dist folder on an orphan branch called `gh-pages` to deploy a static site.

https://github.com/jsfilas/Restaurant-Page/tree/gh-pages This is what GitHub is looking at for your Restaurant-Page.

Another way to deploy GitHub pages is to name your `/dist` folder `/docs` and update your GitHub pages settings to look at the `/docs` folder.

Comment: Hello John, thanks for commenting back. I attempted to do the dist and docs renaming and this resulted in the same outcome here. I am unsure of how to make a gh-pages branch but will look into that.